# Removing white space using sed but skipping Date-Time stamp

Tags: sed, csv-simple

I wanted to remove white space from a CSV file, which I am able to do using `s/\ //g`, but at the same time I want to avoid removing the space between fields which has timestamps e.g. `"06-JAN-15 13:20:00"`: currently it joins them which was expected `"06-JAN-1513:20:00"`.

One solution is to let it delete all the white spaces and then grep for date `06-JAN-15` and add space after it. Not so sure how that can be done.

Sample CSV file: (one line only)

```
294335,"17-APR-15 00:00:00 ",6258,"C"," <-----huge blank space--->,"07-JAN-15 00:00:00"
```

`huge blank space` will contain XML message if not blank.

Comment: Please provide some example lines and your desired output from them..

Comment: ... or are you just trying to collapse any entirely blank *fields*?

Comment: Remove all whitespaces but in between numbers: `s/\([^0-9]\)\s\+\([^0-9]\)/\1\2/g`

Comment: @drewbenn adding " s/  \+/ /g "  removed the blank space with single space. Thanks a lot new output 
294335,"11-JUN-15 00:00:00 ",0,"N"," ",30-JUN-15 13:30:00 "

Answer (score 1):

Not sed, but here's a solution using negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!...)` in perlre.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\d\d-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-\d\d) //g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to clean up the whitespace in the data:

```bash
$ cat file
294335,"17-APR-15 00:00:00 ",6258,"C","                          ","07-JAN-15 00:00:00"
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N clean-whitespace file
294335,17-APR-15 00:00:00,6258,C,,07-JAN-15 00:00:00
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --quote-all clean-whitespace file
"294335","17-APR-15 00:00:00","6258","C","","07-JAN-15 00:00:00"
```

Note that `mlr` removes unnecessary quotes unless you also specify `--quote-all` (which will quote *all* fields).  The `-N` option forces Miller to read the first line as a data record rather than as the header.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
< input awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {gsub(" ", "", $1); gsub(" ", "", $3); gsub(" ", "", $4); gsub(" ", "", $5); print}'
```

This will have the effect of removing any space character from the 1st, 3rd, 4th and 5th comma-separated field in each record.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually parse the file as a CSV file, and strip extra whitespace:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
    row = CSV::parse_line($_)
    puts CSV::generate_line(row.map {|field| field.strip})
' file
```

```
294335,17-APR-15 00:00:00,6258,C,"",07-JAN-15 00:00:00
```